# jQuery: resetting .animated divs position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the following code to expand and center on div on :hover

```
    $(document).ready(function(){         


    //animation on hover            

        $('#sliding_grid li').hover(function() {
          $(this).addClass('highlight');
        }, function() {
          //$(this).removeClass('highlight');
        });

        $(".highlight").live("hover", function(){
            $(this).animate({"width": "454px", "height":"282px", "top: ":"94px", "left":"152px", "margin-top: ":"-94px", "margin-left":"-152px"}, 500);       

        });   

        $(".highlight").live("mouseout", function(){
            $(this).animate({"width": "148px", "height":"90px", "top: ":"0px", "left":"0px", "margin-top: ":"0", "margin-left":"0"}, 500, function(){
             $(this).removeClass('highlight');   
            });        

        });        

    });
```

My problem is two things:

1) I'm not sure how to reset the "top" and "left" css coordinates to their original value on mouseOut.  To see a working demo, go here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kTFvj/1/

2) The z-index (see here: http://jsfiddle.net/kTFvj/1/) is not affecting the :hovered grid elements.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuerys [.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to store the original values and retrieve them on mouseout

I have made a modification to your original code that might work like you wish.. it uses .data and also updates the z-index so the active element is always on top

http://jsfiddle.net/kTFvj/2/

Answer (score 1):

1. as Martin said, store the values when the animation begins using a variable, and restore when done.
2. about z-Index: just have a variable called maxZIndex=0
   and everytime an animation begins, set the object's zIndex property to maxZIndex++

Answer (score 0):

What about using % instead of pixels?

Another solution is saving the actual value of width and height in some vars and restoring on mouse out.